# Best method to check from (JS) client side, if you are connected to server

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, connection, client-server

We are making an application in React, and would like to check after xxx seconds from client end, that if we are connected to our server (WEB API's). 
I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this? 
The instant approach comes to my mind is to call the webApi after xxx seconds using setTimeout from the client side and check the response status.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Why not just attempt an API call whenever you need to, and implement error handling to deal with the possibility that you might not be able to at that point?

Comment: We want to inform the users beforehand that they are disconnected, instead of when they require something from server via webAPI.

Comment: Why? It doesn't matter that they're disconnected until they need something from the server. Polling it all the time seems kind of wasteful (and will be unpopular with users on data caps and/or batteries).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds good. But, as I understand it, a web API is meant
to be called asynchronously and is mostly stateless. Thus, trying to know
if you are connected to your API feels weird to me.

It would make more sense if you were connected to your server using
a websocket, which pseudo real-time. Then, you could check for a connection
or disconnection.